# rpath for third party library

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wrapping a third party library in ROS. The library has a few executables as well. I use a custom Makefile to build the library and the executables. However, when I do "rosrun customlib executable", I get "shared library not found" error. Should I modify the Makefile and use rpath into the executables or is there any default mechanism to take care of such cases? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12143/rpath-for-third-party-library/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the only solution is to ensure rpath is guaranteed by the third party build system. In my case, I was wrapping my own library which uses CMake. I added CMake rpath commands to the library build scripts.

---

Originally posted by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) with karma: 287 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0